# Javascript: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, internet-explorer

I have a problem with the following `javascript` code. When I call the function, in `IE` or `Chrome`'s console I get the error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'childNodes' of undefined

This is the `javascript`:

```
function getline(nline) {
    var combo = window.document.getElementById("combox");
    if (nline == activeline) {
        return;
    }
    if (nline > combo.childNodes[0].childNodes.length) return;
    if (nline <= 0) return;
    if (activeline > 0) {
        if (activeline % 2 == 0) combo.childNodes[0].childNodes[activeline - 1].className = "color1";
        else combo.childNodes[0].childNodes[activeline - 1].className = "color2";
    }
    if (nline > 0) {
        combo.childNodes[0].childNodes[nline - 1].className = "current";
        activeline = nline;
    }
    combo.childNodes[0].childNodes[activeline - 1].focus(); }
```

And `Chrome`'s console says, that the problem is on this line:

```
if (nline > combo.childNodes[0].childNodes.length) return;
```

I read that using the `getelementsbytagname` can be a fix, but I don't know how to adapt to this script.

Update: This is the html part:

```
<script>
  function putfileinit(nline) {
    document.getElementById("divcombo").scrollTop = (nline - 1) * 15;
    getline(nline);
}
</script>

<div id="divcombo" >
    <table id="combox" class="combox" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5"></table>
</div>
<script DEFER>
    putfileinit(1);
</script>
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Please post the HTML of the `combox` element.

Comment: This will happen if `combo` doesn't have any children, so `combo.childNodes[0]` is undefined.

Comment: ¿there is any workaround to declare the childNodes[0] not undefined?

Comment: You can check the length of `combo.childNodes` before trying to access `combo.childNodes[0]`.

Comment: Can't you just check if `combo` has child nodes, `if (combo.childNodes.length > 0) {...` ?

Comment: The `combox` table is empty, so what are you expecting `getline` to do?

Comment: I want to control that when the combox is empty not do anything instead of that i get the undefined.

Answer (score 0):

Just add

```
 if (combo.childNodes.length == 0) return;
```

before

```
 if (nline > combo.childNodes[0].childNodes.length) return;
```